# Running docker on a data pipeline ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-data-pipeline

I am having issues running docker (I cannot connect after the service is started) on an EC2 instance initiated as a ec2Resource - shellCommand in AWS Data Pipeline.

Basically I have a pipeline and part of it is run an ec2Resource, which performs a shell command - that command installs docker (successfully it seems) and then starts the service (again gets back the okay) - but the user cannot then connect to the docker daemon (like it's not running).

Has anyone got this working before?

Can I use, or should I be using a different AMI (I'm running in sydney AU).

Your help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved - run HVM not the default PV, that fixed it right away!